# get value from sensor while phone is in standby mode

Tags: android

is there a change that i can get value from my  phone's sensor when it is in sleep mode? 
If it can, which android version can do that?
Thank you.

Comment: Which sensor are you talking about gps,accelerometer etc?

Comment: I assume that you can do so if your application is a background service which means can run even if it's not foreground you can keep track of accelerometer.

Comment: I,m so sorry, i mean phone is in sleep mode

Comment: Sleep mode you mean the screen is turned off but the device is actually running isnt that it?

Comment: Yes, the screen is off and the device is actually running

Comment: Yeah like i said you can get the values from the accelerometer you just need a write your application as a service which is running as a background process and tracking the accelerometer sensor.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4976/discussion-between-serdar-dogruyol-and-aptos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you can do so if your application is a background service which means can run even if it's not foreground you can keep track of accelerometer.

Even if the phone is in standby mode you just need to write your application as a service which is running as a background process and tracking the accelerometer sensor by doing so.